# Change orientation crash application cause android.support.v4.app.ListFragment

Tags: java, android, android-support-library, android-listfragment

I don't know why application crash on orientation change while using ListFragment ( Support Version ) when i replace `android.support.v4.app.ListFragment` by `android.app.ListFragment`. Every Thing works fine. i don't want to use this method `"android:configChanges="orientation"`.
as a solution of my problem.

- When i rotate my device very first time after launching application ( from portrait to land ) Every
  thing is fine
- but when again ( land to portrait ) ***crash crash crash***

i think problem is with support lib not my code.

MainFragment class code:

```
package com.workout;


import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;


public class MainFragment extends ListFragment {

    public MainFragment() {}


    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(),

   android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,WorkoutDetail.workoutDetails));

        if ( getListView() != null )
            getListView().setOnItemClickListener((MainActivity)getActivity());

    }
}
```

MainActivity Code:

```
package com.workout;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

       // Intent intent = new Intent(this,DetailActivity.class);
       // intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,id);
       // startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

MainActivity XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.workout.MainFragment"/>
```

Logcat Detail:

```
12-14 22:17:58.383 7159-7159/com.workout E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                           Process: com.workout, PID: 7159
                                                           java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment has not been attached yet.
                                                               at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiateChildFragmentManager(Fragment.java:2308)
                                                               at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.getChildFragmentManager(Fragment.java:773)
                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.markState(FragmentActivity.java:967)
                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onSaveInstanceState(FragmentActivity.java:527)
                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onSaveInstanceState(AppCompatActivity.java:509)
                                                               at android.app.Activity.performSaveInstanceState(Activity.java:1419)
                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnSaveInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1301)
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.callCallActivityOnSaveInstanceState(ActivityThread.java:4637)
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4588)
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap19(ActivityThread.java)
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1514)
                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:241)
                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6274)
                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

**i already visit many stackoverflow links but failed to find a solution of my problem.**

Comment: Every fragment is entitled to have an XML view associated with it including in this case a listfragment. Every Activity is entitled to have an XML view associated with it in this case it is an appcompatActivity. You are mixing your main activity XML file with the fragments XML file. XML is static, does not change during execution. Java code is dynamic and changes. An orientation change is a dynamic event and the device has to go through the activity lifecycle to redraw the screen all over again. Its hard to explain this but I will try to help if you have more questions

Comment: Where i am mixing my main activity XML with fragment XML . MainFragment inherit ListFragment and this class doesn't associate with any XML file reason is : list
fragments define their own layouts programmatically. In MainActivity XML i am just adding fragment. Where is Problem ??

Comment: public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity ... setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); but then in activity_main <fragment
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.workout.MainFragment"/>

Answer (score 1):

try remove the listener implementation and onItemClick from activity and use onListItemClick that exist with the listfragment, you do not need to implement listener on listfragment just use the method as below, and hope this may solve your problem.

```
public class MainFragment extends ListFragment {

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    // put your code here
}
}
```

beside the above do the following (I have tested this and it is working)
build new XLM file as follows (copy and paste)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

 <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/FragmentSlot"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

then dynamically add your fragment to the activity as below:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // Begin the transaction
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    // Replace the contents of the container with the new fragment
    ft.replace(R.id.FragmentSlot, new MainFragment());
    // or ft.add(R.id.your_placeholder, new FooFragment());
    // Complete the changes added above
    ft.commit();
}
}
```

this will indeed solve your problem.

yes you are right it is something related to the system when inflating fragment from XLM.

to avoid this in future you need to learn how to use fragment manager and transactions to add, replace, and remove fragments.

check this one, contains three lessons: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html

Comment: This method is also not working..  Problem remain same

Comment: Ok thanks ams73..  This method works.. But can you please tell me why you can't figure out what's the really problem is in my code.. Why statically adding fragment not works. And why this problem is only with support library. android. app.ListFragment .. Works fine On rotation..

Comment: I really do not have an idea. However, statically adding fragments may be helpful during learning or practicing, in reality, you need to add and remove many fragments to your application which may not be possible with static fragments. So good time to start dynamic.